change font style of numbers from footer and main text in cleanthesis
I am using cleanthesis template and using these commands in preamble:
\usepackage[english]{babel} % babel system, adjust the language of the content
\usepackage[                    % clean thesis style
    figuresep=colon,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,%
    hangsection=true,%
    hangsubsection=true,%
    sansserif=false,%
    configurelistings=true,%
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
% LLT: Use biber if using UTF8 encoding
]{cleanthesis}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo} and I also define inside the document body:libe \begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\color{ctcolorblack}\huge\bfseries\fontspec{TeX Gyre Heros}}
\end{document}

Now my question is. Can I change the font of numbers that appear in the main text and in footer given that it does not effect other fonts from other sections of thesis?I want to use TeX Gyre Pagella font.
